# Adding a ListView inside A NestedScrollView

Tags: listview, scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

Almost everyone is suggesting that I should not use a ListView inside a nestedScrollView.However I need to use a nestedScrollView in order to achieve the CollapsingToolbar behavior.I also can't use RecyclerView as some are suggesting since i am using Fabric twitter kit and it does not support RecyclerView (as of now).`myListview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` works but only starting from android 5.0  How can I achieve this.

Here is my code

```
aspirant_profile.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.esir.jualeader.aspirant.AspirantProfile">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/expandedappbar"
        >
        <!--style="@style/CustomActionBarTitleBase"-->
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/album10"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/aspirant_pp_and_aspirant_name"
                >
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/album1"
                    app:border="true"
                    app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
                    app:border_width="4dp"
                    app:shadow="true" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/aspirant_name_and_aspirant_docket"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/aspirant_name_at_profile"
                        android:text="Isaiah"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        style="@style/TextViewHeadline"
                        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                        />
                    <!-- style="@style/TextViewHeadline"-->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/aspirant_docket_at_profile"
                        android:text="Presidency"
                        style="@style/TextViewSubhead"
                        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                        />
                    <!-- style="@style/TextViewTitle"-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >
                        <!--android:theme="@style/TextViewButton"-->
                        <Button
                            android:theme="@style/myBut"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="VOTE UP"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:id="@+id/button_vote_up"
                            android:enabled="true"
                            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Vote For Isaiah"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textViewNote"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            style="@style/TextViewSubhead"
                            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                            />
                        <!--style="@style/TextViewSubhead"-->
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

            <!-- Contain Number Of Votes And Political Party-->
            <RelativeLayout
                style="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    >
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/political_party_circle"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Juele"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/political_party_name"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            style="@style/TextViewCaption"
                            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            />
                        <!--style="@style/TextViewCaption"-->
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <!-- Political Party -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/political_party_name_title"
                        android:text="Political Party"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/political_party_circle"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        style="@style/TextViewSubhead"
                        />
                    <!--style="@style/TextViewSubhead"-->
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    >
                    <!-- Number Of Votes -->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/votes_circle"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        >
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="5,239,888"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/votes"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            style="@style/TextViewCaption"
                            />
                        <!--style="@style/TextViewCaption"-->
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Votes"
                        android:id="@+id/votes_title"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/votes_circle"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        style="@style/TextViewSubhead"
                        />
                    <!-- style="@style/TextViewSubhead"-->
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <!-- Add Layout For The Manifesto-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manifesto"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                style="@style/TextViewHeadline"
                />
            <!--style="@style/TextViewHeadline"-->
            <at.blogc.android.views.ExpandableTextView
                android:id="@+id/expandableTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/longtxt"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:animation_duration="1000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                style="@style/TextViewBody1"
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                />
            <!--style="@style/TextViewBody1"-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/read_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Read More"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
            <!-- Add A ViewPager With ImageView-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Photos"
                android:id="@+id/photos_text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <include layout="@layout/aspirants_images"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Tweets"
                android:id="@+id/tweets_text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
<!-- LAYOUT WITH THE ListView-->
            <include layout="@layout/aspirant_tweets"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

aspirant_tweets.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/aspirant_profile"
    android:id="@+id/aspirant_tweet_layout">
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Loading Tweets..."
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/aspirant_tweets_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#e1e8ed"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            />
       </LinearLayout>`
```

Thanks In Advance.